Reducible/Irreducible Polynomials in Ring Theory
I have this following exercise I've been trying to solve for a while now.
We are supposed to study the irreducibility of the polynomial $A=X^4 +1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ where p is a prime number.
a) Give the irreducible factor decomposition of A in $\mathbb{R}[X]$
I don't see how to do this, I tried using the form $(x^2+aX+1)(x^2+aX+1)$ to figure out the coefficients but I couldn't get anything that would work. I also tried $(X^3 +aX^2+Xb+c)(X+d)$ but again, I didn't get something that would work.
b)Does A have real roots? If A is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, what are the degrees of those irreducible factors?
So here I said that if we can write A as a product of irreducible factors, any root that cancels out each factor would be a root of A. But I'm not really sure where to look for to answer the part about the degrees.
c)Show that A is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$
d) Is A irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$
For part c and d, I used the criteria of Eisenstein.

Let p be a prime number. An element $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a square if there exists $y \in  \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=y^2$

a) What are squares of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
b) Suppose now that $p \geq 3$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ the group of inversibles of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ and $\phi : (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \to (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times $ defined as $\phi(x)=x^2$. Show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism and determine its kernel.
c) What is the cardinal of $Im \phi$
Questions 2a,2b and 2c are very easy, I didn't have any problems
d)Let $\theta: (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \to (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times $ the group homomorphism defined by $\theta(x)=x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. Show that $Im \phi = Ker \theta$
e) From the previous question, show that no matter what the prime number p is, at least three elements -1,2 or -2 is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$
I'm not really sure how I should proceed with 2d and 2e

Consider $A=X^4 +1 \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Show that A is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Give the irreducible factor decomposition of $A= X^4 +1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}$



$X^4+1=(X^2+\sqrt2X+1)(X^2-\sqrt2X+1)$; the roots of $X^4+1$ in $\mathbb C$ are primitive eighth roots of unity $\dfrac{\pm1\pm i}{\sqrt2}$

How can I find $(X^2 + \sqrt2X+1)(X^2 + \sqrt2X+1)$ myself? Should I try $\sqrt2$ as a coefficient of X and play around until I find $X^4 +1$? Also, how do we know that it should be the multiplication of two polynomials of second degree and not a multiplication of a polynomials of first degree and another of third degree?

$X^4+1=0\implies X^2=\pm i\implies X=\dfrac{\pm1\pm i}{\sqrt2}$ and $\left(X-\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(X-\dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)=X^2-\sqrt2X+1\dots$, or $X^4+1=(X^2+1)^2-(\sqrt 2X)^2=(X^2+1+\sqrt2X)(X^2+1-\sqrt2X)$

Solve $X^4+1=0$ over $\mathbb C$ and notice that pairs of complex conjugates combine to form a second-degree real polynomial irreducible over the reals.

Thank you both! Makes so much more sense now!

How about Fermat’s little theorem for 2d?

How I can use Fermat's Little Theorem to show $Im \phi =Ker \theta$?

It shows $y=x^2\implies \theta(y)=1$

Oh I think I see it now, Thank you very much!

I observe that $X^4 + 1$ is a quadratic in $X^2$, so
$$  X^2 = \frac{-0 \pm \sqrt{0-4}}{2} = \frac{\pm 2\mathrm{i}}{2}  = \pm \mathrm{i} \text{.}  $$
Then $X^2 - \mathrm{i} = 0$ and $X^2 + \mathrm{i} = 0$ are also quadratics which one can easily solve, obtaining $X = \frac{\pm{1}\pm{\mathrm{i}}}{\sqrt{2}}$.  None of these are real.  To land back in the reals we must combine complex conjugates.
$$  \left( x - \frac{1 + \mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\left( x - \frac{1 - \mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = x^2 - \sqrt{2}\,x + 1  $$
and
$$  \left( x - \frac{-1 + \mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\left( x - \frac{-1 - \mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = x^2 + \sqrt{2}\,x + 1  \text{.}  $$
(If one is thinking "aren't there other was we could combine these, not in conjugate pairs, to get into $\Bbb{R}[X]$?"  No.  Such a combination would be a polynomial with real coefficients whose roots are complex and not in conjugate pairs, which is something the roots of real polynomials can't do.)
Further, the form you picked, $(x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 + ax + 1)$ has two defects -- the repeated "$a$" (which I suspect is a typo) and the thinking that the "$1$" in $X^4 + 1$ has only one square root.  It has two, so your form should at least allow for $(\dots-1)(\dots-1)$.  From
$$  (x^2 + ax+b)(x^2+cx+d) = x^4 + (a+c) x^3 + (ac + b + d)x^2 + (ad+bc)x + bd  \text{,}  $$
we see
\begin{align*}
a+c &= 0  \\
ac + b + d &= 0  \\
ad + bc &= 0  \\
bd &= 1  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
So $c = -a$ and $d = 1/b$, giving
\begin{align*}
-a^2 + b + 1/b &= 0  \\
a(1/b - b) &= 0  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
The latter admits $a =0$, but the former does not.  The latter admits $b = \pm 1$.  $b = 1$ gives $a = \sqrt{2}$ in the former and $b = -1$ gives $a = \sqrt{-2}$.  Remaining in the reals, $a = \sqrt{2}$, $b = 1$, $c = -\sqrt{2}$ and $d = 1$, giving the same two polynomials we found by combining complex conjugate pairs.
From the rational root theorem, $A$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$.  (The only candidate roots are $\pm 1$ and neither is a root.)
By Gauss's lemma $A$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[X]$.  So it's irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[X]$.
2d) An element of the image of $\phi$ is an $x^2$.  What is $\theta(x^2)$?  (Fermat's little theorem will help.)  If $p = 2$, that's all there is to say since everything is a square.  If $p > 2$, then $(p-1)/2$ is an integer, so $\theta$ sends the non-square residues somewhere.  Either it also sends the non-squares to the same place it sends the squares (which is not what we are to prove) or it sends the non-squares somewhere else.  (As side work: Do an example, say with a non-square modulo 7 to see where $\theta$ sends non-squares.  Do you see why the image of $\theta$ is a subgroup of the group of units?)
2e) If $-1$ or $2$ is a square modulo $p$, you're done.  If neither is a square, then $-1 \cdot 2 = -2$ had better be a square.  This is what you want to show.  Use your work from 2d and the fact that $\theta(-1 \cdot 2) = \theta(-1)\theta(2)$.
3 ) If $2$ is a square modulo $p$, say $m^2 = 2$, then we can replace the "$\sqrt{2}$"s in our factorization in $\Bbb{R}[X]$:
$$ X^4 + 1 = (X^2 + mX + 1)(X^2 - mX + 1)  \text{.}  $$
If $2$ is not a square, then either $-1$ or $-2$ is.  For the former, $n^2 = -1$ (notice that $n$ is a model for $\mathrm{i} \in \Bbb{C}$) and $X^4 + 1 = (X^2 + n)(X^2 - n)$.  (This is the factorization we started with.  Also, you can get this factorization from the factorization over $\Bbb{C}[X]$ by combining the $(x-(1+\mathrm{i})/\sqrt{2})(x-(-1-\mathrm{i})/\sqrt{2})$ roots.  Reminder: we don't expect these coefficients to be real.  Finally, combining the roots in pairs the only remaining way:)  Then, for the latter, let $q^2 = -2$, so that $X^4 + 1 = (X^2 + qX-1)(X^2 - qX-1)$.  In any case, $X^4+1$ is reducible over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.
4 ) By hand calculate the square of $1, \dots, 9$ modulo $19$.  (You don't need to do $-1, \dots, -9$ because those will give you the same list of squares.)  Figure which case from 3) you are in and split $A$ as appropriate.

At the top, isn’t $X^2=\pm i$?

Also, did you forget $/\sqrt2$ in the factorization over $\mathbb C[X]$?

@J.W.Tanner Wait, isn't $\sqrt{0-4} = \sqrt{4}$?  Serious thinko'.  Re: the $\sqrt{2}$ -- got the first one, missed the second one.  Thanks for the catches.   Also in this edit: caught a "$-1 \cdot 2 = -1$" and fixed the right-hand side.
